# How to insert elements in 2d list problem in python

Tags: python, list

I have encountered a problem of insearting elements in a 2d list in python. I have a list called `p` & I have taken 2 random sample from the list.

```
import random
p = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = [i for i in random.sample(p,2)]
```

Then I crated an 2d array of size(2*2)

```
sample = [[0 for i in range(2)]for j in range(2)]
```

Now I can't figure out how to insert the `c` that i have drawn from the list `p` in sample list in the order `[[c1,[c1]],[c2,[c2]]]`

Comment: `sample = [c for i in range(2)]`?

Comment: What is c1, what is c2, what do you mean by "insert"? [ask], [mcve].

Comment: c1 = first random number c2= 2nd random number and insert means to add this c1 and c2 in the sample 2d array

Answer (score 0):

how about doing this.

```
sample = [[p[random.randrange(5)] for i in range(2)]for j in range(2)]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.